# Connecting to a private HBase Cluster

Tags: hadoop, networking, hbase

I have a public HBase cluster on a network with IP 192.168.X.X. I run a java application that retrieves data from the HBase cluster and this app is sitting on same network i.e., 192.168.X.X.

I decided to replicate the cluster and put them into a private cluster with IP 164.128.X.X and my client java app is still sitting on the 192.168.X.X network.

In both cases, I am connecting to the cluster through an edge node sitting on the 192.168.X.X network.

In HBase Java API, the connection is made through zookeeper and my zookeepers are sitting on the private cluster nodes. It should give error because the client java app does not sit on the same network as the private cluster. The HBase Java API does not work anymore because it calls the zookeeper sitting on a different network.

What is a good solution to this issue? I think its a typical setup to have: Client -> Edge -> Private Cluster

Comment: "It should give error" -- Not if your router is setup to send the traffic to where it needs to

Comment: @cricket_007 exactly. Thats what I discovered after setting up some VMS on my laptop. This looks like a networking issue.